# How to add a target .o file to the objects to be linked in openssl build?

Tags: makefile, openssl

I am adding a module  apps/trace.c to be compiled into the openssl programs when building the OpenSSL library.  The purpose is save a trace list of function calls using the gcc -finstrument-functions compile option, as described 

[here](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/trace-and-profile-function-calls-with-gcc/)

Actually, I have succeeded by modifying the automatically generated "Makefile"  by hand, adding in trace.o as follows:

```
apps/openssl: apps/trace.o apps/app_rand.o apps/apps.o ...
    $(RM) apps/openssl
    $(MAKE) -f $(SRCDIR)/Makefile.shared -e \
        PERL="$(PERL)" SRCDIR=$(SRCDIR) \
        APPNAME=apps/openssl OBJECTS="apps/trace.o apps/app_rand.o apps/apps.o ..." \
        LIBDEPS='$(PLIB_LDFLAGS) '" -L. -lssl -L. -lcrypto"' $(EX_LIBS)' \
        CC='$(CC)' CFLAGS='$(CFLAGS) $(BIN_CFLAGS)' \
        LDFLAGS='$(LDFLAGS)' \
        link_app.
```

However, then next time configure is run, the manual change will be overwritten when the Makefile is again automatically generated.

I am not quite sure how to configure the `trace` object file into the compilation at a higher level.  That is my question.

Comment: openssl has its own configuration system (see the `config` and `Configure` scripts). This configuration system generates the Makefiles. Try to understand how it works, its options (the files are well documented) and how to adapt it to integrate your own add-ons. Note: I guess you know it already but what you are trying to do probably completely breaks openssl's security.

Comment: I believe you should modify the `Makefile.orig` files. They are copied to `Makefile` during configuration. There are multiple makefiles, so you might want to `find <openssl dir> -iname 'Makefile*'`. The OpenSSL wiki should probably offer a page on doing something like this (like adding source files to build a new engine).